# Обработка загружаемых изображений

Tags: php, изображения, плагин

Загружаю на сервер с помощью iframe изображения. Есть ли какой-нибудь плагин для их обработки (уменьшение размера, понижение качества и т.д.) или всё надо руками писать?

Comment: А в метку "изображения" ткнуть?

Answer (score 1):

я так понимаю, уменьшение нужно для уменьшения объема данных, передаваемых на сервер?
на джаваскрипте нашел такую функцию... сам, извините, не тестил, но люди пишут, что работает... да и вроде как по коду все логично...

```
function resize(id,xx,yy){
function change_size(elt,img,maxx,maxy){
   var d=Math.min(img.height/maxy,img.width/maxx); 
   elt.style.width=Math.floor(img.width/d)+'px';
   elt.style.height=Math.floor(img.height/d)+'px';
}

var e = document.getElementById(id)
   , img=new Image()
   ,on_complete=function(){
      change_size(e,img,xx,yy);
   };
img.src=e.src;
if (img.complete) on_complete();
img.oncomplete=on_complete;
}
```

Принимает айди изображения (`<img/>`), и желаемый размер, до которого уменьшить...

Comment: Эта функция всего лишь меняет ЛИНЕЙНЫЕ размеры изображений НА КЛИЕНТЕ. Что никак не сказывается ни на "весе" файлов, ни на количестве передаваемого по сети.